# Script gerador de captcha em PHP não gera a imagem

Tags: php, captcha

Estou tentando rodar o script do site abaixo, que gera captcha, mas a imagem nunca é gerada. Alguém pode me dar uma luz do que posso estar fazendo? Estou rodando o script via docker.

Página: https://www.devmedia.com.br/captcha-simples-com-php/17444

**index.php**

```
<!--
No campo src da tag img abaixo enviaremos 4 parametros via GET
l = largura da imagem
a = altura da imagem
tf = tamanho fonte das letras
ql = quantidade de letras do captcha
-->
<img src="captcha.php?l=150&a=50&tf=20&ql=5">
<!--
O texto digitado no campo abaixo sera enviado via POST para
o arquivo validar.php que ira vereficar se o que voce digitou é igual
ao que foi gravado na sessao pelo captcha.php
-->
<form action="validar.php" name="form" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="palavra"  />
   <input type="submit" value="Validar Captcha" />
</form>
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?php
   session_start(); // inicial a sessao
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // define o tipo do arquivo

    function captcha($largura,$altura,$tamanho_fonte,$quantidade_letras){
        $imagem = imagecreate($largura,$altura); // define a largura e a altura da imagem
        $fonte = "arial.ttf"; //voce deve ter essa ou outra fonte de sua preferencia em sua pasta
        $preto  = imagecolorallocate($imagem,0,0,0); // define a cor preta
        $branco = imagecolorallocate($imagem,255,255,255); // define a cor branca

        // define a palavra conforme a quantidade de letras definidas no parametro $quantidade_letras
        $palavra = substr(str_shuffle("AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtUuVvYyXxWwZz23456789"),0,($quantidade_letras)); 
        $_SESSION["palavra"] = $palavra; // atribui para a sessao a palavra gerada
        for($i = 1; $i <= $quantidade_letras; $i++){ 
        imagettftext($imagem,$tamanho_fonte,rand(-25,25),($tamanho_fonte*$i),($tamanho_fonte + 10),$branco,$fonte,substr($palavra,($i-1),1)); // atribui as letras a imagem
        }
        imagejpeg($imagem); // gera a imagem
        imagedestroy($imagem); // limpa a imagem da memoria
    }

    $largura = $_GET["l"]; // recebe a largura
    $altura = $_GET["a"]; // recebe a altura
    $tamanho_fonte = $_GET["tf"]; // recebe o tamanho da fonte
    $quantidade_letras = $_GET["ql"]; // recebe a quantidade de letras         
que o captcha terá
    captcha($largura,$altura,$tamanho_fonte,$quantidade_letras); //         
executa a funcao captcha passando os parametros recebidos
?>
```

**validar.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
    if ($_POST["palavra"] == $_SESSION["palavra"]){
        echo "<h1>Voce Acertou</h1>";
    }else{
        echo "<h1>Voce nao acertou!</h1>";
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Retornar</a>";
    }
?>
```

**Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado no log de erros do PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está correto, o que está ocasionando erro é um problema muito comum na função `imagettftext()`. O problema de anexar a font ao texto no `fontfile` da função.

Segundo o **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)**:

> Dependendo de qual versão da biblioteca GD o PHP está usando, quando
>   fontfile não inicia com um leading / then .ttf será anexado ao nome do
>   arquivo e a biblioteca tentará procurar por esse nome ao longo de um
>   **caminho de fonte definido pela biblioteca**.

Quando eu tentei usar a fonte igual a você, no mesmo diretorio assim:

```
 $fonte = "arial.ttf";
```

A imagem veio quebrada. 
Basta você comentar essa linha para ver o erro:

```
 // header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

**Erro:**

> imagettftext(): Invalid font filename

Quando eu alterei para caminhos absolutos:

```
 $fonte = "C:/Windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
 // ou
 $fonte = "C:/wampp/www/app/fontes/arial.ttf";
 // ou
 $fonte = "C:/xampp/htdocs/app/fontes/arial.ttf";
```

O resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma outra opção que o manual aconselha, caso você esteja usando a imagem no mesmo diretório é fazer isso:

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
$font = "Arial";
```

Comigo não funcionou. Prefiro fazer isso:

```
$fonte = getcwd()."/arial.ttf"; // isso funciona
```

Como o `getcwd()` não haverá problemas quando o script for para produção.

Comment: Consegui corrigir o código conforme vc me instruiu aqui, muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: @danielfr3 tranquilo! Aconselho você usar o `getcwd()`, pois quando você colocar em produção, não haverá problemas.